# mongo db $push finding maximum number of something

Tags: python, mongodb

i wanted to write pipleline code, that gives me the 5 users with the most tweets, i tried to use $push, i looked up the mongo db documentation and it also showed $sort. I get an syntax error on the text line, but atleast to me it is not an obvious one. 
Would be really nice if someone could point me in the right direction, since i watched some videos and read pages, but did not find what is wrong with my code.

```
pipeline = [
            {"$group" : {
                        "_id": "$user.screen_name",
                        {
                        "$push": {"texts" : "$text"}},
                        {
                        "$sort" : {"texts":-1}}},
                        {
                        "$limit" :5}}   

            ]
```

Comment: Hello Stephan. We all hope that the answers you find here on StackOverflow are useful to you. If it is so, please remember that [you _should_ vote up and/or accept those answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting is especially important as this will mark the question as "answered" and will provide feedback about how you solved your issue to other users coming to this question from the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **[aggregation pipeline document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)** gives you a very good structured way on how aggregation works, with examples.

***And as per your question, you are asking the same things more than once.***

Anyway, in your query `$group` should not contain `$sort` and `$limit` **[check syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)**, and `$push` is placed wrongly **[$push syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)**. So your aggregation query should be as below:

```
pipeline = [{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$user.screen_name",
    "teet_data": {
      "$push": {
        "texts": "$text"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "texts": -1
  }
}, {
  "$limit": 5
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I've never used aggregation pipeline of MongoDB. What is `"teet_data"` ? Is it an arbitrary name for the result "record" ?

Comment: Good luck with getting your valid answer accepted ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux yes `tweet_data` is an arbitrary name

Comment: @chridam Thank you for explaining that. Did I mention that I'm not the OP? ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Sorry for the misunderstanding, that was meant for the answerer as the OP has never accepted any previous good answers on questions which are somehow related :P

Comment: Honestly i did not know about accepting the answer or how someone does it. Now i know and will do it of course from now on. Thank you for explaining it to me !

Comment: @StephanKetterer it would be a good idea to go through your old questions and accept those answers that have helped you now you know how - will help to keep a good name on the site :)

Answer (score 1):

*"I wanted to write pipleline code, that gives me the 5 users with the most tweets"*

I can't say if this is an improvement over @yogesh' answer, but given your description, you only need to *count* the tweets. Not to pass them all along your pipeline. At the very least, using a `$sum` would be much more memory efficient:

```
pipeline = [{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$user.screen_name",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "count": -1
  }
}, {
  "$limit": 5
}]
```